# How can I guarantee the order that objects are instantiated in Powershell?

Tags: multithreading, powershell

It's fairly simple to time a block of code using `Measure-Command`, `[system.diagnostics.stopwatch]` or by diffing a couple of `Get-Date` calls, but here's the weird thing;

When I wrap `Measure-Command` with two date objects, sometimes `Measure-Command.TotalMilliseconds` is longer than `($EndTime - $StartTime).TotalMilliSeconds`.

Is the `$EndTime` object being instantiated before `Measure-Command` finishes?

Why does this still happen if I run single-threaded; `powershell.exe -sta`?

Is there any way to force `$EndTime` to be set after `Measure-Command` ends?

Is there any guarantee `StartTime` has been created before `Measure-Command`?

Clearly this particular method is not a sensible way to evaluate code execution time.

```
$Stopwatch = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::startNew() 
$mc =Measure-Command{Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.google.com" -Method Head}
$Stopwatch.stop()


$mc.TotalMilliseconds
$Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds
"="
 $Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds - $mc.TotalMilliseconds


"`n"

$StartTime = (get-Date)
$mc = Measure-Command{Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.google.com" -Method Head}
$EndTime = (get-Date)

$mc.TotalMilliseconds
($EndTime - $StartTime).TotalMilliSeconds
"="
($EndTime - $StartTime).TotalMilliSeconds - $mc.TotalMilliseconds #This should never be negative but sometimes it is.

"`n"

$mc1 =Measure-Command{$mc2 = Measure-Command{Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.google.com" -Method Head}}

$mc1.TotalMilliseconds - $mc2.TotalMilliseconds
```

Example output

```
122.3065
122.4322
=
0.125700000000009


142.8695
140.6371
=
-2.23240000000001


0.104199999999992
```

Comment: `STA` does not mean there isn't concurrency.  See [this article on the matter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/processes--threads--and-apartments).  It is the default execution mode for powershell.  It would be useful if you posted the output of your commands *in your question*.

Comment: Please note that `(Get-Date) - (Get-Date)` does _not_ produce accurate high-resolution intervals, so you're sort of comparing measurements from an atomic clock vs someone recounting "1 mississippi, 2 mississippi, etc" and therefore you shouldn't expect it to be accurate. Use a `[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]` instead

Answer (score 3):

Oh boy, that's a lot of interesting questions, although I sense you may have been led astray by the fact that not all methods of measuring are equal - so let's go through them!

> Why does this still happen if I run single-threaded; `powershell.exe -sta`?

Because this is not a threading or concurrency issue

> Is there any way to force `$EndTime` to be set after `Measure-Command` ends?

Yes, by splitting them into separate statements (as you've already done)

> Is there any guarantee `$StartTime` has been created before `Measure-Command`?

For the same underlying reasons as the previous answer; yes!

> Clearly this particular method is not a sensible way to evaluate code execution time.

Aaaaaaand, you just gave yourself the answer :)

---

## DateTime.Now is a terrible source for accurate interval measurements

`Get-Date`, without any parameters specified, returns the value of `DateTime.Now`

Although `DateTime.Now` returns a `DateTime` struct with a high degree of *precision*, its value is obtained by querying the operating system for the current wall-clock time, and this interaction does not produce a result that is *accurate* commensurate its potential *precision* - for more on this I'd suggest reading this [blog post by Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime/)

You'll likely see a lot of "jitter" rather than a normal interval distribution if you tested it with something like:

```
$timestamp = Get-Date
0..9 |%{
    $timestamp - ($timestamp = Get-Date)
} |Select Ticks
```

In this example I'm even comparing the `Ticks` property rather than `TotalMilliSeconds`, getting values with (supposedly) 10000 times the precision - if you compared `TotalMilleseconds` instead you're even likely to get results of on a modern PC `0`.

---

`Measure-Command` internally uses a `StopWatch`, which in turn uses the [`kernel32!QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter) API, which provides a much more precise source of linear interval measurements, since its unaffected by wall-clock jitter and synchronization - and this is exactly the reason you never see this discrepancy when you use `[StopWatch]` for the outer measurement

Comment: Nicely done; curiously, the accuracy of `DateTime` seems to have improved in .NET Core; the OP's symptom doesn't surface in PowerShell _Core_.

Comment: That sounds likely (although on windows anything using QPC is still probably the most accurate)

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57431959/45375) - whose main point bears repeating: **use [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) for the most accurate time measurements available**, don't use `System.DateTime`:

As a minor point: **If you *do* use `System.DateTime`** - for convenience, in cases where accuracy isn't paramount - **use `[DateTime]::UtcNow` rather than `[DateTime]::Now`**, for two reasons:

- Using UTC (`UtcNow`) works anytime: unlike *local* time (`Now`) it isn't affected by DST (daylight-saving time) transitions.

  - However, you're still susceptible to realtime-clock changes due to *time synchronization*.
- There is no benefit in translating UTC to local time in this case (which also slows things down, though only marginally so).

Curiously, **the accuracy of `System.DateTime` seems to have *improved* in .NET *Core*** (cross-platform) vs. .NET Framework (Windows-only), and **therefore also in PowerShell *Core*** vs. Windows PowerShell.

That is, in my test the symptom you describe no longer surfaces in PowerShell Core, on any supported platform, whereas it can reliably be reproduced in Windows PowerShell.

The simplest test is to do the following:

```
# Loop for as long two *consecutive* [datetime]::UtcNow calls
# report the *same* tick count.
while (([datetime]::UtcNow - [datetime]::UtcNow).Ticks -eq 0) { write-host -nonewline . }
```

If `[datetime]::UtcNow` is accurate enough to detect that time has elapsed between two consecutive calls to it, the loop should  *never* be entered.<sup>[1]</sup>

- That is indeed what happens in PowerShell Core.
- By contrast, in Windows PowerShell, the two consecutive calls *typically* report the *exact same point in time*: you'll see many dots and never *none*.
  Eventually, a difference is reported, after a wildly varying number of iterations.

The same applies to a variation of your code:

```
$i = 0
do {

  Write-Host . -NoNewline
  ++$i

  $StartTime = (get-Date)
  # Note: the specific command being measured is incidental to the issue.
  $mc = Measure-Command { $PSVersionTable } 
  $EndTime = (get-Date)

  $diff = ($EndTime - $StartTime).TotalMilliSeconds - $mc.TotalMilliseconds #This should never be negative but sometimes it is.

} while ($diff -ge 0)
Write-Host
"Took $i try/tries to get negative value: $diff; DateTime timespan: $(($EndTime - $StartTime).TotalMilliSeconds)"
```

The code loops and prints a dot in each iteration until the difference in timespans is unexpectedly negative.

PowerShell Core keeps printing dots indefinitely, while Windows PowerShell stops after 1 - 2 iterations.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell's need to initially interpret and then JIT-compile its code certainly slows the individual calls down, compared to precompiled code. Running compiled C# code `while (true) Console.WriteLine((DateTime.UtcNow - DateTime.UtcNow).Ticks);` still gives you `0` in .NET Core, but only about *two thirds* of the time in my tests, whereas in .NET Framework it seems to be *exclusively* `0`.</sup>